# Problem with external log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I can't load log4j.properties from an external file. This works, but I need to pass the location to it from the server.xml. The server is Liberty.
This works for the configuration.properties and the configuration.properties:
server.xml:

```
<jndiURLEntry id="url/propiedades.conf" jndiName="url/propiedades.conf" value="file:${server.config.dir}conf/" />
```

resource-beans.xml:

```
<bean id="beanPropertiesProyecto"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>${url/propiedades.conf}configurationBean.properties</value>
                <value>${url/propiedades.conf}configuration.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

For the file log4j.properties this works:
resource-beans.xml:

```
<bean id="log4jInitializer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod"
            value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
            <value>file:${server.config.dir}conf/log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But this doesn't work

```
<bean id="log4jInitializer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod"
            value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
            <value>${url/propiedades.conf}log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Throws this bug:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'log4jInitializer' defined in class path resource [beans/business/resource-beans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'url/propiedades.conf' in value "${url/propiedades.conf}log4j.properties"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'url/propiedades.conf' in value "${url/propiedades.conf}log4j.properties"
```

All three files are in the same directory.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a property to "configuration.properties".

Bean:

```
    <bean id="log4jInitializer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod"
            value="org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${log4j.dir}/log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

configuration.properties:

```
 log4j.dir = ${server.config.dir}conf
```